# Jpa Repository findByForeignKey does not work

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, orm, one-to-many

Hey guys I've been working Spring Jpa. I have a Comment Model and Post Model. There are many to one relationship between them. What i want to do is i want to get the all comments according to given post id. But the when i run the program;  "No property 'id' found for type 'Post'" is the error message. It happens same for the YeditepeUserDetailsId. Can you help me?

Here is my Comment Model

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
    private Long commentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) // post silindiğinde yorumları da sil
    @JoinColumn (name = "postId", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name = "yeditepeUserDetailsId", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) // post silindiğinde yorumları da sil
    private YeditepeUserDetails yeditepeUserDetails;
    private String comment;
    private int likes;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

and here is my Comment Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {
    
    List<Comment> findByYeditepeUserDetailsIdAndPostId(Long yeditepeUserDetailsId, Long postId);

    List<Comment> findByYeditepeUserDetailsId(Long yeditepeUserDetailsId);

    List<Comment> findByPostId(Long postId);

    Comment findByCommentId(Long commentId);
}
```

But the when i run the program;  "No property 'id' found for type 'Post'" is the error message. It happens same for the YeditepeUserDetailsId. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First you know that jpa findBy- naming rules.
Jpa makes a query depending on field name.
In Comment entity, name of Post entity is "post".
So you should make a method name like this.

```java
    List<Comment> findByPost(Post post);
```

I think there are two options.
This is my example code for you.

##### Context for Test

This is the context for my test.

###### Comment Entity

```java
package blog.in.action.domain;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long commentId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId", nullable = false)
    private Post post;
    private String content;
}
```

###### Post Entity

```java
package blog.in.action.domain;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long postId;
    private String title;
}
```

###### CommentRepository

- These are two options.

  - Using Jpa naming rules for method.
  - Using `@Query` annotation.

```java
package blog.in.action.domain;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    List<Comment> findByPost(Post post);

    @Query("select comment from Comment comment where comment.post.postId = :postId")
    List<Comment> findByPostId(@Param("postId") long postId);
}
```

###### PostRepository

```java
package blog.in.action.domain;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

##### Test for First Option

- Follow Jpa naming rules for JpaRepository.

```java
package blog.in.action.comment;

import blog.in.action.domain.Comment;
import blog.in.action.domain.CommentRepository;
import blog.in.action.domain.Post;
import blog.in.action.domain.PostRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
public class CommentTests {

    @Autowired
    CommentRepository commentRepository;
    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @Test
    void using_entity_as_a_parameter() {
        Post post = Post.builder()
                .title("Hello World")
                .build();
        postRepository.save(post);
        Comment firstComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is first comment")
                .build();
        Comment secondComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is second comment")
                .build();
        Comment thridComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is third comment")
                .build();
        commentRepository.save(firstComment);
        commentRepository.save(secondComment);
        commentRepository.save(thridComment);


        List<Comment> result = commentRepository.findByPost(
                Post.builder()
                        .postId(post.getPostId())
                        .build()
        );


        assertThat(result.size(), equalTo(3));
        assertThat(result.get(0).getContent(), equalTo("this is first comment"));
        assertThat(result.get(1).getContent(), equalTo("this is second comment"));
        assertThat(result.get(2).getContent(), equalTo("this is third comment"));
    }
}
```

###### Result of Test

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into post (title, post_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select comment0_.comment_id as comment_1_0_, comment0_.content as content2_0_, comment0_.post_id as post_id3_0_ from comment comment0_ where comment0_.post_id=?
```

##### Test for Second Option

- Using `@Query` annotation.

```java
    @Test
    void using_query_annotation() {
        Post post = Post.builder()
                .title("Hello World")
                .build();
        postRepository.save(post);
        Comment firstComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is first comment")
                .build();
        Comment secondComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is second comment")
                .build();
        Comment thridComment = Comment.builder()
                .post(post)
                .content("this is third comment")
                .build();
        commentRepository.save(firstComment);
        commentRepository.save(secondComment);
        commentRepository.save(thridComment);


        List<Comment> result = commentRepository.findByPostId(post.getPostId());


        assertThat(result.size(), equalTo(3));
        assertThat(result.get(0).getContent(), equalTo("this is first comment"));
        assertThat(result.get(1).getContent(), equalTo("this is second comment"));
        assertThat(result.get(2).getContent(), equalTo("this is third comment"));
    }
```

###### Rusult of Test

```
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into post (title, post_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, post_id, comment_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select comment0_.comment_id as comment_1_0_, comment0_.content as content2_0_, comment0_.post_id as post_id3_0_ from comment comment0_ where comment0_.post_id=?
```

Answer (score -1):

The way your entities are setup is such that you should be fetching comments from the posts side of the relationship.  Presumably, your `Post` entity class looks something like the following:

```java
@Entity
public class Post {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Now you may select a post and its comments using the following JPQL:

```
from post p inner join p.comments c where p.id = ?
```